# Facebook likes with multiple third-level domains or switching domains

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, dns, switching

Is it possible to configure a Facebook app to have FB likes on a website "aggregated" on different third-level domains?
So, for instance, all the likes on http://example.com/page-to-like are the same of http://www.example.com/page-to-like and https://secure.example.com/page-to-like ?

This could be very important also in case of switching to a new domain (third or second level). It's really incredible that with a domain switch all the likes will be erased...isn't it?

I already searched about on Google, Facebook and here without success, so I think that it's not possible to to this but this is the last try.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Either of these will work:

1. On all three pages, point the like buttons to one of the pages, all likes will accumulate on the page you point the like buttons at.
2. On the three URLs, set your `og:url` meta tag to point to the canonical URL for that content (i.e pick the 'main' URL for that content)

Comment: Hi lgy, thx for your answer. I think that the first is the way to go. The second one is not ever possible due to possible change of the canonical URL (it's ok for search engine if the old one redirect with a 301 or point to the new one in the canonical, but it's not ok for FB). Anyway also the first one doesn't consider another use case: what if I used for instance all the likes on http://example.com and I want to switch all my platform to http://www.example.com? If I don't want to lose all the likes of the past I have to maintain forever the old domain...or are there any other solutions?

Comment: Yes, you have to maintain a single canonical URL even if other methods of accessing that content change - see my answer here for a longer explanation and solution: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7197919/how-can-i-move-a-url-via-301-redirect-and-retain-the-pages-facebook-likes-and-o/10152342#10152342